# Does the polynomial $r^3+s^3+t^3-3rst-1$ have rational roots?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, number-theory, determinant

I am looking at natural numbers $n$ of the form

$$n=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc) = \det \left(\begin{array}{rrr}a & b & c \\c & a & b \\b & c & a\end{array}\right) $$

with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Suppose we can find rational numbers $r,s,t$ such that:

$$1 = r^3+s^3+t^3-3rst = (r+s+t)(r^2+s^2+t^2-rs-rt-st) = \det\left(\begin{array}{rrr} r & s & t \\ t & r & s \\ s & t & r \end{array}\right)  $$

Then we would have a new "solution" for $n$:

$$n = n\cdot 1 = (a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc)(r^3+s^3+t^3-3rst) = u^3+v^3+w^3-3uvw$$

So the question is if the group:

$$G := \{ (r,s,t) | r,s,t \in \mathbb{Q} , \det(r,s,t) = 1 \}$$

has some interesting points?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the proper generalization of this are circulant matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: Substituting $t=0$ gives $r=\sqrt[3]{1-s^3}$. Choosing different values of $s$ gives a set of solutions.

Comment: A question extremely similar to this was asked on the 2019 putnam exam. Check out solution A1. https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2019s.pdf I don't know if it even helps, but I recognized that equation.

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks, I know this. Those matrices are call group determinants as defined by Dedekind. In this case the group is the cyclic group $C_3$.

Comment: @Explorer: Is the solution a rational number?

Comment: @Chessnerd321: Thanks for your help. This is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, that this it what you are looking for:

$\gamma:=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$

$A^3+B^3+C^3-3ABC=D^3 \enspace$ with $\enspace D:=(a+b+c)(a+\gamma b+\gamma^2 c)(a+\gamma^2 b+\gamma c)$

and therefore $\enspace D= a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc\,$ .

So, you'll get $\,A,B,C\,$ expressed by $\,a,b,c\,$ which means, that with rational numbers $\,a,b,c\,$ the numbers $\,A,B,C\,$ and $\,\frac{A}{D},\frac{B}{D},\frac{C}{D}\,$ are also rational.

Comment: What are $A, B, C$ please?

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: You're welcome. ;)

Comment: @OlivierRoche : ... $\,A,B,C\,$ expressed by $\,a,b,c\,$ ... means: $\,A,B,C\,$ are terms of $\,a,b,c\,$ . You'll get these terms if you multiply out $\,D^3\,$ .